# Aligning four circle's inside a square in CSS and HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, alignment

I am developing a Simon Says game, and have all the working JavaScript, etc.

The main problem I am having is with the CSS; everything works when you click it,

Here is a mock image of what I want it to look like:

[image]

update still having alingment problems have updated my CSS

[image]

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.back {
width:700px;
height:700px;
background-color:black;
}

.pad {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.shape1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -300px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.shape2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.shape3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.shape4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.level, .score {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.sButton {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.start {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="back">
            <div class="pad shape1" data-pad="1">
                <audio preload="auto" class="sound1">
                    <source src="sounds/mp3/sounds_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
                    <source src="sounds/ogg/sounds_01.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
                </audio>
            </div>
            <div class="pad shape2" data-pad="2">
                <audio preload="auto" class="sound2">
                    <source src="sounds/mp3/sounds_02.mp3"  type="audio/mpeg"/>
                    <source src="sounds/ogg/sounds_02.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
                </audio>
            </div>
            <div class="pad shape3" data-pad="3">
                <audio preload="auto" class="sound3">
                    <source src="sounds/mp3/sounds_03.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
                    <source src="sounds/ogg/sounds_03.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
                </audio>
            </div>
            <div class="pad shape4" data-pad="4">
                <audio preload="auto" class="sound4">
                    <source src="sounds/mp3/sounds_04.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
                    <source src="sounds/ogg/sounds_04.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
                </audio>
            </div>
            <div class="break"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="level">
            <h2>Level: 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="score">
            <h2>Score: 0</h2>
        </div>

        <ul class="difficulty">

            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="2">Easy
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="1" checked>Normal
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="0.5">Hard
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="0.25">Insane
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="sButton">
            <button class="start">start</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: To make them circles, you can simply add a `border-radius` of, say, 25 to 30px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to give your shapes an absolute position and use the "top", "left", "right" and "bottom" css properties like so:

```
.shape1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Note that margin-top is used to slightly offset the "top" property. Border-radius will turn these into circles.

Comment: i was able to make them cirlces but I am still having trouble with the alignment inside the black box I have posted an image above of the problem, hopefully u can help ?

Comment: I recommend inspecting these elements inside Chrome's developer tools or another toolset. If the shape should be at the top, give it `top:0` and `left:50%`. Compare that to my example of .shape1 (which you changed for some reason). I think that you are having trouble with CSS positioning. I would recommend reading up on that as well.

Comment: the reason i changed your example is because the circle completely disappeared and i was only left with 3 ?

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Just make sure that .shape1 has `margin-top:-50px;` and that shape should look right.